# Como dividir strings em partes iguais

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

Como dividir um `texto` com ou mais de **20.000 caracteres** em partes iguais e cada parte contendo **5000 caracteres**? (NodeJs)

Tenho essa função:

```
textBreak = (data) => {
  const characterCounter = data.text.length;
  const pagesCounter = data.numpages;
  var text = data.text;
  var math = Math.round(characterCounter / pagesCounter) + 3000;
  var index = 0;
  var array = [];
  while (index < characterCounter) {
    array.push(text.substr(math, Math.min(index + math, text.length)));
    index += math;
  }
  console.log('textBreak: sucess');
  return { array, pagesCounter, characterCounter, math }
}
module.exports = textBreak;
```

Comment: O que você fez até o momento? [Edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/441112/edit) a  pergunta e adicione um [mcve] mostrando como tentou resolver o problema para que possamos lhe dar as orientações sobre o que já fez.

Comment: @AugustoVasques pronto

Comment: Mas você quer quebrar em 5000 fixo ou conforme data.numpages?

Comment: Sim, fixo. Essa função n ta boa, acho q nem precisa do numpages, só tava fazendo um calculo pra ter um ideia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um possível solução, seria fazer um `while` na string conforme o seu tamanho (`length`) e dentro do `while`, você ir quebra a string com `substring`, pegando um trecho dela e adicionando em um array, assim a string vai diminuindo enquanto o array vai tendo novas posições.

```js
function breakString(string, size) {
  //Valor default de 5000
  size = size || 5000;

  let breakStr = [];

  while (string.length > 0) {
    breakStr.push(string.substring(0,size));
    string = string.substring(size,string.length);
  }

  return breakStr;
}

let bigString = "abcdefghij".repeat(2000);

//Quebrar com o tamanho padrão de  5000
console.log(breakString(bigString));

//Quebrar de 130 em 130...
console.log(breakString(bigString, 130));

//Exemplo para verificar se a string de entrada é a mesma de saída
console.log( bigString == breakString(bigString, 147).reduce( (acc, value) => acc += value , "") );
```

Comment: Eu tentei fazer uma função async para pegar cada posição do array breakStr e adicionar um comentario no começo da linha, tipo 'Block 1', mas n consegui. Vc poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Tipo "Block 1 - abcdefg"?

Comment: Na verdade fiz a pergunta errada, quero que antes de adicionar no array breakStr, cada bloco do loop adicionado no array tenha uma tag, Tipo, A string é "abcdefg" e por exemplo o "abc" é um bloco, ficaria assim "Bloco 1: abc", por isso pensei em async/await. Deu pra entender? To nisso a uns 3 dias :v

Comment: Se entendi, seria algo assim: https://repl.it/repls/AchingRemorsefulOffices ou https://repl.it/repls/VirtualLightyellowProgramminglanguages

Comment: Aaaa exato, muito obrigado

Answer (score 3):

O que você ta procurando é a função que foi declarada aqui:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033639/split-large-string-in-n-size-chunks-in-javascript

```js
function chunkString(str, length) {
    return str.match(new RegExp('.{1,' + length + '}', 'g'));
}
```

Caso prefira usar como um polyfill (como é o meu caso) você pode usar o código abaixo (ele precisa rodar antes de inicializar qualquer coisa, afinal é um polyfill):

```js
(window => {
    if (!('chunk' in String)) String.prototype.chunk = function(length) {
        return this.match(new RegExp(`.{1,${length}}`, 'g'))
    }
})(window)
```

Ao adicionar o polyfill, basta agora chamar a função em qualquer campo string, assim:

```js
console.log('12345678'.chunk(2))
// result: (4) ["12", "34", "56", "78"]
```